# razor syntax error while trying to divide (remainder) by 2 in clause statement?

Tags: c#, razor, razor-2

How do you do this in ASP.NET Razor when trying to divide/remainder rowCounter by 2 ??  I get red underline syntax error saying "cannot implicity convert type 'long' to 'bool'

```
long rowCounter = 0;

foreach(var v in modelResult)
{
    @:<tr class='@(rowCounter % 2 ? "even" : "odd")'>

    rowCounter++;
}
```

Thanks...

Comment: Try `@(rowCounter % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd")`

Comment: Alternatively, you can accomplish this via CSS using nth-child(even) and nth-child(odd) selectors for the table in question and set your CSS for even and odd rows. E.g. `#mytable tr:nth-child(even){ css goes here }`

Comment: @ emgee - good point on the use of tr:nth-child(odd) ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the result of `rowCounter % 2` is a `long`, not a `bool`. You need to compare the result to something to see if `rowCounter` is actually odd or even. Try this:

```
@:<tr class='@(rowCounter % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd")'>
```